# How to update only non-empty values in a table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

How do I update only the non-empty values?

I have an SQL code for updating a result set.

But after I submit my form, the values I did not input would also be updated and record as empty values in the database.

Here is my code

```
$insert = "UPDATE result SET test_1= '$test_1', test_2= '$test_2', 
                 test_3= '$test_3', test_4= '$test_4', 
                 test_5 = '$test_5' 
                WHERE roll_no = '$roll_no'";
```

And the form

```
 <form action="#" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="test_1" required="" class="" >
 <input type="text" name="test_2" required="" class="" >
 <input type="text" name="test_3" required="" class="" >
 <input type="text" name="test_4" required="" class="" >
 <input type="text" name="test_5" required="" class="" >
 <button type="submit" class="" name="sub">SUBMIT</button>
```

If i fill in only *test_1* and *test_2*, i want other columns to be unaffected, since there are no inputs.

Comment: What is not empty, the column or variable? If variables build the query dynamically.

Comment: In your code check if they aren't entered, and if they aren't, set that variable = something and put it in your update query. Like if name is empty or not entered, assign name = "not supplied".

Comment: Some of the variables would be empty but the columns will contain a value. When i submit, expecting only the input i filled in to update (eg: test_1 and test_2 only), the whole columns update instead.

Comment: @clearshot66 You don't understand me. Okay let me add my form to the question

Comment: can you show us an example? Looks like we dont understand what you need.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you would need a way to determine that there was "no input" for a given form field. Let's assume that the form field will be provided, and that the value will be a zero length string.

That is, we can do a conditional test of the value assigned to a variable (e.g. $test_4`) to determine if that is a value of we to store, or if it's "no input", which we want to disregard.

---

In SQL, it's possible to evaluate an expression, and return a value.  As an example, the ANSI-standard:

```
 CASE WHEN foo = '' THEN bar ELSE foo END
```

Or MySQL-specific shorthand:

```
 IF(foo = '',bar,foo)
```

In an UPDATE statement, it is possible to reference the current value of a column, and we can return that in an expression...

```
UPDATE mytable t
   SET t.col = IF(foo='',t.col,foo) 
 WHERE ...
```

If `foo` is equal to a zero length string, then the expression returns the current value of the column. And that will be assigned back to the same column, resulting in "no update" of the column value. (Note that if there's a "before update" trigger defined on the table, the trigger would fired, and that could potentially modify the value of `NEW.col`.)

---

Assuming that the value `$test_4` has been properly escaped to mitigate potential SQL Injection vulnerabilities, and there's some reason we can't use a prepared statement with bind placeholders...

Assuming that we are going to let a zero length string stored in `$test_4` represent "no input"

We could do something like this:

```
UPDATE result r 
   SET ...
     , r.test_4   = IF('$test_4' = '', r.test_4, '$test_4')
 WHERE ...
```

The more ANSI-standard way to express that

```
UPDATE result r 
   SET ...
     , r.test_4   = CASE WHEN '$test_4' = '' THEN r.test_4 ELSE '$test_4' END
 WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to the query you posted then `COALESCE` can help you in this case.

```
UPDATE result
SET test_1 = COALESCE('$test_1', test_1), test_2 = COALESCE('$test_2', test_2),
  test_3   = COALESCE('$test_3', test_3), test_4 = COALESCE( '$test_4', test_4),
  test_5   = COALESCE('$test_5', test_5)
WHERE roll_no = '$roll_no';
```

---

MySQL `COALESCE()` function returns the first non-NULL value of a list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

**Example :** MySQL `COALESCE()` function

```
mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL, 2, 3);
+----------------------+
| COALESCE(NULL, 2, 3) |
+----------------------+
|                    2 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, NULL);
+----------------------------+
| COALESCE(NULL, NULL, NULL) |
+----------------------------+
|                       NULL |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Note:** This will only work if the empty values are in fact `NULL`. `NULL <> Empty`

Comment: I think this is the solution but the parameters are inverted. For what I understand the `$test_1` is the variable from the page and that is what can be `NULL`...   So `COALESCE('$test_1', test_1)`  will assign the variable `$test_1` only if is not `NULL` otherwise retain the previous value.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JuanCarlosOropeza. Your opinion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Try ifnull function as given below:

```
UPDATE result 
SET test_1 = ifnull(test_1,'$test_1'), 
    test_2 = ifnull(test_2,'$test_2'), 
    test_3 = ifnull(test_3,'$test_3'), 
    test_4 = ifnull(test_4,'$test_4'), 
    test_5 = ifnull(test_5,'$test_5') 
WHERE roll_no = '$roll_no'
```